# In c#, how to assign a sql query result within a variable?

Tags: c#, sql, insert, subquery

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString());
    string select = "SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK";
    string insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,select) VALUES (121,4)";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insert,connection);
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here I got exception where the insert contains invalid string select.
Please tell me how assign sub query within the insert?

Comment: Why you are using select query inside insert query?

Comment: **did you try your query on SQL Query browser?** If not try it once. *If it works there it will definitely work with my code*

Comment: I think now you would understood why I'm using select statement.  (I had edited the select statement).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with sub query inside Insert query

Comment: exactly.  insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK) VALUES (121,4)" ------ this works but through select variable I cant. I need Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use a select statement like this 
if you want to use a sub query it has to be in single statement

but in above statement you write in different different statement for selection 
and insert query .

so `cmd.ExecuteNonquery()` execute only `insert` text statement so SQL engine unable to find `SELECT`(and SELECT is a Reserved keyword) so it gives you a error

if you go with subquery try this

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString());

string select = "SELECT 121, (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK";
string insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,[select]) "+select;

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insert,connection);
```

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: How can I do the select within an insert query using c#?

Comment: so you want select and insert in single query ?

Comment: insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK) VALUES (121,4)" ------ this works but through select variable I cant.  I need Help.

Comment: the code that you have give showed an exception : 'Invalid cloumnname select'

Comment: insert.ExecuteQuery()-- wrong.  It should be sqlCommand.ExecuteQuery(). --please edit your answer.  I changed it but showed exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, you have to Execute query on `SQLCommand` object not on string object try this

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString())){
string insert = "Insert Query";
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insert,connection))
{
 con.Open();
 int i = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

### Update:

```
 var selectQuery = "SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK";
 var insertQuery = string.format("INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,{0}) VALUES (121,4)",selectQuery);
```

Comment: can you explain why to have new variable i?

Comment: That's your wish actually you can use it or not, that will have the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

Comment: @AnantDabhi Why you are getting that doubt

Comment: the updated ans showed error :"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list".

Comment: you will get that error if you did something wrong in `string.format()` can you show your string.format() code

Comment: I tried it, actually it is not format(); It should be Format().  I changed it but exception.

Comment: var insert = string.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,{0}) VALUES (121,4)", + select);

Comment: I didn't write like this DO I?, If you are using string.Format you are not supposed to use `+` for concatenation??

 `string.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,{0}) VALUES (121,4)",  select);`
Try this

Comment: It shows incorrect syntax near the SELECT.  anything wrong in that?

Comment: Did you test your query using Sql Server Management Studio? Is it giving proper results?

Comment: ya the select query gave me the proper result.  Also would like to tell you that insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.BOOK (book_id,SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(page_no) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MAX(page_no)+1 END) FROM dbo.BOOK) VALUES (121,4)" this works properly.

Comment: I am not good in SQL What I will do is Test a sample sql in SSMS before using in program. For me if the query works in ssms it will work in program. Check once again whether the full query is working in your SQL Server or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your query results will return a `DataTable`. So use a `DatAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`.